# Hadoop Installation on Windows: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: hadoop

I am getting **Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable** error while trying to install the hadoop version 2.8.3 on my windows 10.

I have set below environment variable in hadoop-env.cmd file:
set HADOOP_OPTS=%HADOOP_OPTS% -Djava.library.path=%HADOOP_HOME%/lib/native

also, I have added below configuration

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>  
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>/F:/tools/hadoop-2.8.3/data/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>/F:/tools/hadoop-2.8.3/data/datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>

I have renamed mapred-site.xml.template file to mapred-site.xml
```

Please let me know if I have done something wrong here

I am stuck in this installation since so long. PLease help.

Comment: None of these xml files fix that **warning**. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Hadoop should work without Native libraries, just less optimally (besides, running it on Windows already isn't optimal)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with hadoop 2.9.1 on windows 10. I was able to format namenode but unable to start-dfs.

I build correctly the sources in my development host for windows platform (including winutils.exe and hadoop.dll) using visual studio 2017 community, mvn, etc, following building.txt recommendations, but when I try to run in a clean windows 10 installation I was facing the unable to load native hadoop-library error on startup of the dfs node.

I run winutils.exe and give me an error:

> "Missing VCRuntime140.dll"

I installed vc++ 2015 x64 redistributables and solved the problem, namenode ans datanode up. No need to setup env variables apart from HADOOP_HOME, and follow the edits in hadoop-env.com explained in https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows.

Also, that's the results with hadoop checknative command:

> C:\APACHE\HADOOP\bin>hadoop checknative
>   18/09/08 18:23:35 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
>   18/09/08 18:23:35 WARN zlib.ZlibFactory: Failed to load/initialize native-zlib library
>   winutils: true C:\APACHE\HADOOP\bin\winutils.exe
>   Native library checking:
>   hadoop:  true C:\APACHE\HADOOP\bin\hadoop.dll
>   zlib:    false
>   snappy:  false
>   zstd  :  false
>   lz4:     true revision:10301
>   bzip2:   false
>   openssl: false build does not support openssl. 
>   winutils: true C:\APACHE\HADOOP\bin\winutils.exe

Answer (score -5):

window operating system is not optimal for installing of hadoop you can use ubuntu for installation and u can dual boot your system and can use both operating system in a single system and for hadoop installation in ubuntu you can use following [article](https://knowledgebase598784031.wordpress.com/2018/06/18/hadoop-single-node-cluster-installation-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, But as per **[https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows]** site, hadoop2 onwards, It has native support for windows, So what does that mean

Comment: the statement you are getting is not an error its just warning you can ignore that it will not effect your working in hadoop

Comment: @Guarav It means you must compile those native sources for your own operating system. They are not included in the Hadoop binary download